# Is this cast iron pan safe to cook in?

Tags: cast-iron, pan

My wife just bought this pan and I noticed this weird dark/black spot in the center with a bit of a swirl around it (never mind the brownish tint, this is due to my flax oil seasoning).

I don't care much about the looks, I'm just worried this might be unhealthy to cook in. Does anyone know what that might be?

[image: cast iron pan]

Comment: Did this stain appear after seasoning it? Your seasoning looks quite thick and uneven, so it might even be some impurity that got stuck while seasoning.

Comment: @Johanna It was definitely there before I season it, including the swirling marks

Comment: In that case, regardless of if it's safe or mot, I would request a replacement from the store you bought if from. You're unlikely to get a smooth surface regardless of how much you season it and the seasoning will most likely just flake off around the swirl marks.

Comment: @Johanna Please feel free to add your comment in an answer so I could mark it as solved

Answer (score 2):

From [Johanna](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/users/31313/johanna) in the comments section:

> In that case, regardless of if it's safe or mot, I would request a replacement from the store you bought if from. You're unlikely to get a smooth surface regardless of how much you season it and the seasoning will most likely just flake off around the swirl marks.

*Turning the helpful comment given into an answer as comments are temporary.*